# Error 404 . xampp htdocs issue in local access

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, xampp

I am new in PHP

I download and install xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz file on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS with this command:

```
 tar xvfz xampp-linux-1.7.3a.tar.gz -C /opt
```

Solved htdocs trouble with this command:

```
 sudo chmod 777 -R /opt/lampp/htdocs/
```

and seted password with this command:

```
 sudo /opt/lampp/lampp security
```

In my browser i go to localhost address and everything is ok. but when i brows to my site that located in htdocs folder (newsite) this error occurs:

```
 Object not found!  

 The requested URL was not found on this server. If you entered the URL manually please check your spelling and try again.  

 If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.  
 Error 404  
 localhost  
 Sun 22 Jul 2012 11:38:05 AM IRDT  
 Apache/2.2.21 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.21 OpenSSL/1.0.0c PHP/5.3.8 mod_apreq2-20090110/2.7.1 mod_perl/2.0.5 Perl/v5.10.1
```

I very searched the web but i didn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you `chmod` the htdocs folder after adding mysite to it? Run your `chmod` command again and then restart Apache.

Comment: tanx m1ket. first I comment some lines in /opt/lampp/lampp file but again enable this comments and I install ia32-libs and run chmod command and based your above comment I restart lampp. and now anythings is OK. Tanx anyone.